# std::map<int,bool> wrong result of insert?

Tags: c++, stl

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::map<int, bool> set;
    
    cout << (int)set.insert({ 5,false }).second << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know why the result is 1 instead of 0, while `second` is false.

Comment: Try `cout << set.insert({5, false}).first->second << endl;`

Comment: The value that's **inserted** contains `false`. The value that's **returned** contains `true`. Read the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::map::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert)'s return value is an `std::pair<iterator, bool>` where the `bool` denotes whether insertion took place. `cout << (int)set.insert({ 5,false }).second << endl;` will only print whether insertion successfully took place.

To do what you want, you'll want to use the first value in the returned `std::pair` which is an iterator and then use that to check the value of the new key/value pair that you inserted:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::map<int, bool> set;
    std::cout << set.insert({5, false}).first->second << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```